# Compiling difference between gcc and cmake compilation - ldd command

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cmake

I need to create shared library using cmake.
It compiles, but ldd command shows that not all links found.

GCC build:

```
gcc -g -Wall -O0 -m64 -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs  -fPIC -shared -o libcore.so  -Iinclude -Iinc -Itls -Llib64 -Wl,-rpath,protocol_so:lib64:libwifi -DLINUX -DCPU_64 -lprotocol_common -lthread -lvip -lcrypto -lglib-2.0 -lm -lpthread -lxml2
```

ldd command:

```
> ldd libcore.so 
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff30fff000)
        libachk.so => /lib64/libachk.so (0x00007f2d9d7b5000)
        libprotocol_common.so => lib64/libprotocol_common.so (0x00007f2d9d6b1000)
        libthread.so => lib64/libthread.so (0x00007f2d9d5af000)
        libvip.so => lib64/libvip.so (0x00007f2d9d20d000)
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f2d9cef2000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f2d9cd19000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2d9caa0000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2d9c882000)
        libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f2d9c526000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2d9c1af000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2d9bfaa000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f2d9bda1000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2d9ba9b000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2d9b884000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2d9dbf1000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f2d9b66e000)
```

Now I need to build this library with cmake.
Cmake script:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(core_lib C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOGEN_VERBOSE ON)

set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_COMMON "-g -std=gnu89 -Wall -O0 -m64 -fPIC -DLINUX -DCPU_64")
if(NOT CMAKE_C_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY)
    set(CMAKE_C_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY
            "<CMAKE_C_COMPILER> <CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_C_FLAGS> <LANGUAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_CREATE_C_FLAGS> <SONAME_FLAG><TARGET_SONAME> -o <TARGET> <OBJECTS> <LINK_LIBRARIES>")
endif()

file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES
        *.h
        *.c
        )
add_library(core_lib SHARED
        ${SOURCE_FILES}
        )
set_target_properties(core_lib PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)
set_target_properties(core_lib PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS " ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_COMMON}")
set (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs -shared -Wl,-rpath,protocol_so:lib64:libwifi")
target_link_libraries(core_lib  -L${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/..)
target_link_libraries(core_lib  -L${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib64)
target_link_libraries(core_lib  -lprotocol_common -lthread -lvip -lcrypto -lglib-2.0 -lm -lpthread -lxml2)
target_include_directories(core_lib PUBLIC
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../inc
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../tls
        )
```

Some of generated commands:

```
/usr/bin/gcc  -Dcore_lib_EXPORTS -g -fPIC -I/home/user/cmake_libs/core_c/../include -I/home/user/cmake_libs/core_c/../inc -I/home/user/cmake_libs/core_c/../tls  -g -std=gnu89 -Wall -O0 -m64 -fPIC -DLINUX -DCPU_64 -o CMakeFiles/core_lib.dir/log.c.o   -c /home/user/cmake_libs/core_c/log.c

/usr/bin/gcc  -fPIC -g -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs -shared -Wl,-rpath,protocol_so:lib64:libwifi -shared -Wl,-soname,libcore_lib.so -o libcore_lib.so CMakeFiles/core_lib.dir/log.c.o CMakeFiles/core_lib.dir/logic.c.o CMakeFiles/core_lib.dir/json.c.o CMakeFiles/core_lib.dir/msg.c.o CMakeFiles/сore_lib.dir/buf.c.o -L/home/user/cmake_libs/core_c/.. -L/home/user/cmake_libs/core_c/../lib64 -lprotocol_common -lthread -lvip -lcrypto -lglib-2.0 -lm -lpthread -lxml2
```

ldd command:

```
> ldd libcore_lib.so 
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff329ff000)
        libachk.so => /lib64/libachk.so (0x00007f9a91007000)
        libprotocol_common.so => not found
        libthread.so => not found
        libvip.so => not found
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f9a90d40000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9a90ac7000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9a908a9000)
        libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f9a9054d000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9a901d6000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9a8ffd1000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f9a8fdc8000)
        libpcre.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.0 (0x00007f9a8fb98000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9a9146a000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f9a8f981000)
```

Why some of links not found in cmake build?
I see no difference between building versions.

What do I miss? May be some flags at linkage stage?

**UPD.**

Also it is interesting, that gcc links libs from my lib64 folder.

Cmake links from /usr/lib64, but I didn't add this path. (eg. libglib-2.0.so.0)

Why cmake ignores my custom path for libs (lib64)?

Comment: Your CMake build is looking for the libraries here `/home/user/cmake_libs/core_c/../lib64`, but it's not clear if your GCC build is looking there. Are there libraries in that folder that conflict with your system's libraries in `/lib64/`?

Comment: @squareskittles, libprotocol_common.so , libthread.so, libvip.so, libcrypto.so.1.0.0 are only in my custom folder located. There are some duplicates in my lib64 and system /lib64/ but with other libs.

Comment: @squareskittles, gcc definitely takes looking in my lib64 folder, I checked that. Also I changed in cmake path for libs from ```/home/user/cmake_libs/core_c/../lib64``` to ```/home/user/cmake_libs/lib64``` - and nothing happend

Comment: Do you run the `cmake` and `make` commands from the same directory where you run your explicit `gcc` command? Will the CMake-handled linking be done in the same directory? With your explicit `gcc` command you use relative paths for the `-L` option and `-Wl,-rpath` options, but in the `CMakeLists.txt` file you show you have absolute paths for the `-L` options but keep the relative path for the `-Wl,-rpath` option. Make sure that the paths for both `-L` and `-Wl,-rpath` matches. The important option here is the `-Wl,-rpath` option.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I love you

Comment: Also, in your CMake `target_link_libraries` commands, you shouldn't have to bother with the `-L` and `-l` flags; you only need to specify the library names or paths.

Answer (score 0):

As said @Someprogrammerdude,

> > Make sure that the paths for both -L and -Wl,-rpath matches. The important option here is the -Wl,-rpath option.